# Javascript firstChild returns EmptyTextNode in Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I've tested and in browsers(Opera, Chrome, FireFox) .firstChild function works correct, but in Edge it returns EmptyTextNode.

```
document.getElementById('breadcrumbsCategoryContainer').firstChild
```

Does there Edge has some alternatives, for this function?

Comment: It would be *really useful* if you included the HTML in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a function, it's a property.

It sounds like the other browsers are removing whitespace prior to the first tag inside the container, and IE Edge isn't. If so, you can use `firstElementChild` to get the first child that's an *element*. Note that support for `firstElementChild` is good, but some older browsers don't have it.

Alternately, use `firstChild` and a loop, skipping past any blank text nodes.

Comment: Can you please share a sample code. How do I replace my    firstElementChild with what you suggested? TIA